# ONVIF - Python + ZEEP: create_service not working

Tags: python, wsdl, onvif, zeep

I'm implementing an application using ONVIF protocol. There is a WSDL file https://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl which I have to work with. But it's necessary to define default service, to add following code into WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:service name="DeviceService">
    <wsdl:port name="DevicePort" binding="tds:DeviceBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://ip_address/onvif/device_service"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

But it's not possible due to these points:

1. to add the Node into the WSDL file, you have to download the WSDL file (this is not a real problem, because I downloaded the file due to performance - for now)
2. the application should communicate with many IP cameras in various networks, so it's not possible to define line: `<soap:address location="http://ip/onvif/device_service"/>`

So I was looking for some solution and I've found it in Zeep documentation (http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/client.html#creating-new-serviceproxy-objects), where is written:

> There are situations where you either need to change the SOAP address from the one which is defined within the WSDL or **the WSDL doesn’t define any service elements.**

So I've tried to call this:

```
client = Client(
    wsdl = '/path/to/local/wsdl_file.wsdl',
    wsse = self.InitSecurity(),
    service_name = 'DeviceService',
    port_name = 'DevicePort'
)

service = client.create_service(
    '{http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl}DeviceBinding',
    'http://ip_address/onvif/device_service'
)
```

But when I run the script, following exception is thrown:

> ValueError: There is no default service defined. This is usually due to missing wsdl:service definitions in the WSDL

And when I modify WSDL file directly (add the Node above), everything works correctly.

Any idea, please? I'm fighting with a while, so I need to kick a little bit.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service = client.create_service() should work (see also https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/106 for the same wsdl).

Are you using the created service object for subsequent calls (e.g. `service.Operation()` instead of the client?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me, but I wish :-(. After your answer I noticed my version of Zeep (0.21.0), and I thought it could be because of it. But according to release date it should contain working create_service() method. Nevertheless, I've updated to 1.1.0 but still not working - the same exception is thrown (no default service defined). And with "subsequent calls", I think I am - I'm calling client.service.Operation(), is it ok? Is the piece of code I wrote above correct (I mean code for client and create_service)?

Comment: No that's the reason it gives you the error actually. the client.service object is a default mapping. Since you create a new one with the create_service you need to use that instead. so my_service = client.create_service(..); my_service.operaton()

Comment: So, your advice was the answer - but in combination with specific version of Zeep. It's little bit odd, but when I installed Zeep of versions from 0.21.0 to 0.24.0, it works perfectly, when I installed Zeep of versions 0.26.0 and 0.27.0, it works just one of X requests (in other X-1 requests it threw an exception I'll describe further) and when I installed Zeep of versions 1.0.0 and 1.1.0, there was everytime thrown an exception: "http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response". So I've tried to upgrade each dependency, but it won't help. Thank you again.